bpy.types.AddonPreferences no longer working for a legacy addon updated to a 4.2 extension
I'm in the process of converting a legacy add-on to a 4.2 extension. I currently can seem to get my preference class to appear in bpy.context.preferences.addons. Currently I have this code:
class ExtensionPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __package__
    bl_label = "Add-on Preferences"

    variable: BoolProperty(
        name="test variable",
        description="this is to test prefernces",
        default=True,
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "variable")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExtensionPreferences)

where i attempt to grab the preferences in another operator with:
prefs = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__package__].preferences
print("preferences: ", prefs)

and get
preferences:  None

If i check bpy.context.preferences.addons it contains 'bl_ext.file.foldername' whether I register the preferences operator or not. If I try to register the preference class under a different name, it wont appear in bpy.context.preferences.addons.
I'm wondering whether preferences need to be defined differently in an extension, I was following the steps outlined here to convert between addons and extensions:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/extensions/addons.html
